# A single exception handler for multiple possible exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to check the results from a C# database call to make sure ..

1. The DataTable returned is NOT NULL
2. The DataTable has rows (DataTable.Rows.Count > 1)

If either of these conditions are true I want to return the same exception as this type of result is not expected, there should always some records. Is there a way to do this without repeating the throw exception statement?

```
if (myDataTable != null) 
{
  if (myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0) 
  {
    myRow = myDataTable.Rows[0];
  } 
  else 
  {
    throw new Exception("Problem obtaining data");
  }
} 
else 
{
  throw new Exception("Problem obtaining data");
}
```

I don't need to differentiate between these exceptions for my purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
if (myDataTable != null && myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
    myRow = myDataTable.Rows[0];
} 
else 
{
    throw new Exception("Problem obtaining data");
}
```

You don't need to nest the if statements

Comment: In C# 6 you could write `if (myDataTable?.Rows.Count >0)` and avoid the null check

Comment: Marked as answer because I like the idea of having the exception in the `else`. Answer from @sebastien was also correct. Sorry.. had to choose one.

Comment: It might be worth adding a small explanation about short-circuit evaluation of `&&` and `||` for those who are unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply write:

```
if (myDataTable == null || myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0) 
{
    throw new Exception("Problem obtaining data");
} 
myRow = myDataTable.Rows[0];
```

Comment: I think the null check is inverted :)